# Running Fabric command in Seperate Process Group Hanging

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing, fabric

I'm having trouble understanding exactly why this is hanging. I have stripped down this example to the core components. I have a file, let's call it `do_ls.py`

```
import fabric.api
import time

host = "myhost.mydomain"
username = "username"
password = "password"

def main():
    with fabric.api.settings(host_string=host,user=username,password=password):
        result = fabric.api.run("ls")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I run this command: `python do_ls.py` it will execute correctly. Now for the problem. I would like to run this in it's own process. So I have this file, let's call it `main.py`

```
import sys
import os
import logging
import subprocess as sp
import time

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    cmd = [sys.executable, "/path/to/do_ls.py"]
    p = sp.Popen(cmd, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
    while p.poll() is None:
        print "Sleeping..."
        time.sleep(0.5)
    print "All Done."

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Now if I run `python main.py` this will hang forever. The problem as far as I know is that I'm running the process in a subgroup (i.e. if I take out `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` then it will work correctly). What I don't understand is, why this is the case. Especially given that the following works:

```
    cmd = ["ssh", "-q", "username@hostname", "ls"]
    p = sp.Popen(cmd, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since the following lines work:

```
cmd = ["ssh", "-q", "username@hostname", "ls"]
p = sp.Popen(cmd, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
```

but `main.py` continuously hangs, I assume that

```
while p.poll() is None:
```

never evaluates to `False`. So `p.poll()` must always be returning `None`, possibly even after the process completes. A quick search returned [this conversation](http://bugs.python.org/issue2475) on Python's bug reporting site. As per that conversation, try calling `sp.Popen()` with the (undocumented) `_deadstate='dead'` option:

> The problem is that `os.wait()` does not play nicely with `subprocess.py`.
>   `Popen.poll()` and `Popen.wait()` use `os.waitpid(pid, ...)`  which will
>   raise OSError if pid has already been reported by `os.wait()`.
>   `Popen.poll()` swallows OSError and by default returns None.
>
> You can (sort of) fix your program by using
>   `p.popen(_deadstate='dead')` in place of `p.popen()`.  This will make
>   `poll()` return `'dead'` instead of `None` if OSError gets caught, but this
>   is undocumented.

Comment: Hey Ryan. Thanks for the response. I'm still using poll in the "working" example, I simply replaced what command I was executing. Sorry if that part was confusing. So I don't think this is the problem. I was simply saying that a different command was working. Thanks again.